# How to make everything on stdout be read aloud (using espeak)?

Tags: command-line, sound, accessibility, text-to-speech, stdout

I've got the eSpeak TTS system up and running, and I like it quite a bit.

I'm wondering, is there a way to pipe EVERYTHING that gets printed to STDOUT to espeak? I'm trying to set up a system without a monitor that would speak the terminal output to me.

I've found the brltty-espeak package, but I have no idea how to set it up.

Answer (score -1):

You can just pipe it like:

```
<your command> | espeak
```

Comment: Nope, what I'm looking for is something that will automatically do that for every command I type. My ultimate goal is to have a computer set up without a monitor, which will just read all of stdout to me.